# How do I add a custom field in Magento's registration form?

Tags: magento

The field will be two dropdown boxes which should contain all categories available. One box will contain the categories and the second will contain products under that category. The product selection options will be updated automatically according to the selected category.

Comment: If you show us what you have tried already it will be a lot easier to help

Comment: Really, you should show attempts, rather than simply ask. Do some research, and show it to us, so we know where to start. Incidentally, I retagged your question because, though this system may use Ajax, that's not really going to be relevant to people trying to answer it.